# Real-time Firebase Issues

Tags: firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to add some info in my realtime-database with android Studio, but I cant.  Its just a String but in my database nothing appears. I changed the rules to:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth.uid !== null",
    ".write": "auth.uid !== null"
  }
}
```

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR8bO.png)[Real-time databases](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q36gK.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It sounds like there's an issue with your code or maybe authentication but without seeing that code, it's just a guess. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Show us the code that you're using to write the data and the code for the authentication.